# C# get values of registry subkeys

Tags: c#, registry

I have something like that in registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MyKeys\Keys1
  > random subkey 1 / value a = 1
  > random subkey 2 / value b = 2
  > random subkey 3 / value c = 3
  > random subkey 4 / value d = 4
```

random subkey x - random numbers (for eg {6E7EE186-9G13-50HC-A001-319DA68183A7})

Now I want to save all of subkeys names to string[] and then add each value to listView:

```
a | 1
b | 2
c | 3
d | 4
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: HKCU\Software is usually more appropriate location to store app specific data

Comment: I forgot to say in my answer that, you have to decide how to handle security and unauthorized exceptions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is an example to retreive subkeys + values from specific key

```
    class Key
    {
        public string KeyName { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> Values { get; set; }
    }

    private List<Key> GetSubkeysValue(string path, RegistryHive hive)
    {
        var result = new List<Key>();
        using (var hiveKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, RegistryView.Default))
        using (var key = hiveKey.OpenSubKey(path))
        {
            var subkeys = key.GetSubKeyNames();

            foreach (var subkey in subkeys)
            {
                var values = GetKeyValue(hiveKey, subkey);
                result.Add(values);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Key GetKeyValue(RegistryKey hive, string keyName)
    {
        var result = new Key() {KeyName = keyName};
        using (var key = hive.OpenSubKey(keyName))
        {
            foreach (var valueName in key.GetValueNames())
            {
                var val = key.GetValue(valueName);
                var pair = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(valueName, val);
                result.Values.Add(pair);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

call `GetKeyValue` with your root path(SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MyKeys\Keys1 in your question)
and local machine hive

**Notes**:

There are cases where `OpenSubKey` return `null`, in my example those cases will throw NullRefrenceException => you should decide what will happen when `OpenSubKey` return `null`

Your path is in local_machine - software, make sure that you are using the right `RegistryView`

Comment: I think "var values = GetKeyValue(hiveKey, subkey);" was supposed to be "var values = GetKeyValue(key, subkey);"

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, I had to make modifications.

```
public class RegistryFuncs
{
    public static List<Key> GetSubkeysValue(string path, RegistryHive hive)
    {
        var result = new List<Key>();
        using (var hiveKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, RegistryView.Default))
        using (var key = hiveKey.OpenSubKey(path))
        {
            var subkeys = key.GetSubKeyNames();

            foreach (var subkey in subkeys)
            {
                var values = GetKeyValue(hiveKey, path, subkey);
                result.Add(values);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Key GetKeyValue(RegistryKey hive, string path, string keyName)
    {
        var result = new Key() { KeyName = keyName };
        var subkey = $@"{path}\{keyName}";
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subkey))
        {
            if (key == null) return null;

            foreach (var valueName in key.GetValueNames())
            {
                var val = key.GetValue(valueName);
                var pair = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(valueName, val);
                result.Values.Add(pair);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class Key
{
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> Values { get; set; }

    public Key()
    {
        Values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
    }
}
```